# How to split objects in a list retrieved from an SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, list, python-3.3, split

I'm on python 3.3, trying to create a form of 'log in' function. However, I don't know how i'd split the list 'I've retrieved. Its in this format at the minute.

```
[('AdamBaker1',), ('PaulBaker2',), ('DanBaker3',), ('CarolBaker4',), ('ClaireBaker5',), ('PaulBaker6',), ('ChrisBaker7',)]
```

However, I want the program to accept when just the text (for example, 'CarolBaker4') is entered from a user input.

Comment: This is really a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you need to show us your select code, because you can ask the database to match the user input for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of rows; each SQL result row consists of just one column, because that is all you selected, but your select could have returned more than one column.

Just pick out each first element:

```
results = [row[0] for row in results]
```

Now you have a list of strings, instead of a list of tuples of strings.

You can also test if a given string (from user input) is in your list:

```
if any(row[0] == username for row in results):
    print('User found')
```

However, if you are getting a username input from the user, don't ask the database for all usernames. Ask instead if the username exists in the database:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ?', (username,))
if cursor.fetchone():
    print('User exists')
else:
    print('Error: no such user')
```